# PubNub Subscribe in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, pubnub, openwrt

Here is my code

```
PubNub = require('pubnub');


var pubnub = new PubNub({

    subscribeKey: "sub-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    publishKey: "pub-xxxxxxxx"

});


pubnub.subscribe({

    channel : 'test_chan',
    message : function(m){
        console.log(m)
    },
    error : function (error) {
        // Handle error here
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
```

Operating System : OpenWRT

NodeJS version : v0.12.7 (That is the only available for OpenWRT)

PubNub version : 2.11.3 (did npm install pubnub)

The code works on other Linux & Windows platforms. 
Publishing works. 
But subscribe just does not happen. There is no error response either. 
It just sits there
Checking the presence shows the subscribe did not happen at all.

Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: You indicate PubNub NodeJS SDK v2.11.3 - this can't be true as we are on v4.0 now and there aren't any v2.x out there. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubnub. Just want to verify the version. But you say publish works - where is your publish code? Subscribe will just sit there until a message is published on the channel it is listening to.

Comment: Any updates @searcot jabali?

Comment: @CraigConover: Yes. We managed to get it to version 4.0.0 just yesterday. 
Thank you

Comment: So upgrading is your answer to your question? Curious which version of PubNub Node SDK you were using that you had issues because it does work, so want to provide a valid answer other than upgrade here.

Comment: @CraigConover: I dont think I can replicate the error again. We upgraded all our hardware to 4.0.
I will post the logs if the error pops up again